# How to set background colour in the the Grails excel-export / apache-POI plugin?

Tags: excel, grails, export, apache-poi

We are using the Grails [excel-export plugin](https://github.com/TouK/excel-export) which uses apache-poi under the hood.

We are trying to set the background colour (and later font) of a cell (or row).

We have tried this:

```
def rgb = [50,50,50] as byte[]
XSSFColor colour = new XSSFColor(rgb)
headers.eachWithIndex() {item, i ->
  xlsxExporter.putCellValue(row, i, item.value.toString())
  def style = xlsxExporter.getCellAt(row, i).getCellStyle()
  xlsxExporter.getCellAt(row, i).setCellStyle(style.setFillBackgroundColor(colour))
};
```

But nothing changes.  we tried putting the setCellStyle before plutCellValue, but this results in a null pointer exception.

We can't use a template, because we are developing a plugin, and only applications can have accessible files in the WEB-INF, not plugins, unfortunately.

-- update 1

Tried this:

```
  def style = xlsxExporter.getCellAt(row, i).getCellStyle()
  style.setFillBackgroundColor(colour)
  style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.ALIGN_FILL)
  xlsxExporter.getCellAt(row, i).setCellStyle(style)
```

Didn't help.

-- update 2

Tried using a template xlsx.  In the template I changed whole rows to have a background colour. The resultant output has all cells with data written having no background, and the remaining cells having the background. I.e. if you write any data, it overwrites the templates style, which is the opposite of what the documentation says. I raised it as a bug with the plugin website.

```
  // convert the headers into a list of strings for the exporter.
  headers = response.rows[0].keySet()
  List<String> headersList = []
  headers.eachWithIndex() { item, i ->
          headersList.add(item.value.toString())
  }

  // copy the raw row data into a list of lists for Exporter
  def exports = []
  response.rows.each {
         exports << it
  }

  xlsxExporter = new WebXlsxExporter(servletContext.getRealPath("/reporting/report_template.xlsx")).with {
         fillHeader(headersList)
         add(exports, headersList)
         save(outputStream)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
style.setFillBackgroundColor(colour)
```

Try this:

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(color)
style.setFillPattern(style.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
```

Check whether it helps

Comment: Hi, are you sure we need to set style SOLID_FOREGROUND for setting the background colour?

Comment: Ok, tried this, and, bazzarly, setting the foreground sets the background. Who defined those methods?  However, its having a really strange effect.  It is changing the background colour of any cell written, including cells written before the cells which have their background colour set.  It looks terrible. how do you only change the background for a specfic cell or group of cells, if setting it for one cell sets it for all cells?

Comment: You need to provide the range obviously..like from which cell till which cell you wanna set the background

Comment: I am getting the handle of a particlar cell, getting its style, updating the style, then writing the style back to that cell, for the particular cells I want to style.  unfortunately, its affecting all cells written, even those written before I set any style.

Comment: Can you post that part of the code which is causing this?